# Is there a way to skip unuseful frames from stack trace for issue title in Setnry?

Tags: grouping, fingerprint, sentry

I have a stack trace like

```
KERNELBASE.dll                  0x7ff9afcbcd29      RaiseException
VCRUNTIME140.dll                0x7ff9a100647f      _CxxThrowException (throw.cpp:74)
engine.dll                      0x7ff91358fa79      engine::CrashService::syntheticCrash (crash_service.cpp:195)
```

Default Sentry grouping will take the first frame of the stack and will set the title of the issue as "RaiseException". But this is actually bad naming for the issue (I suppose I will get more of different crashes grouped with the same name and I will have to ungroup them manually somehow) and I'd like to skip first 2 frames so that issue title would be "engine::CrashService::syntheticCrash". Is there a way to do that?

I know I can change `title` of the issue in fingerprint rules, but how can I get 3rd frame's function name? `{{stack.function}}` always returns first frame of the stack.

I also tried to change Stack Trace Rules (using `^-group -group ^-app -app` for unuseful frames) but it does not affect issue title sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this guide:
https://docs.sentry.io/product/data-management-settings/event-grouping/stack-trace-rules/

The part you need:

> ### Cut Stack Traces
>
> In many cases, you want to remove the top or bottom of the stack trace.
> For instance, many code bases use a common function to generate an
> error. In this case, the error machinery will appear as part of the
> stack trace.
>
> For example, if you use Rust, you likely want to remove some frames
> that are related to panic handling:
>
> ```
> stack.function:std::panicking::begin_panic       ^-app -app ^-group -group
> stack.function:core::panicking::begin_panic      ^-app -app ^-group -group
> ```
>
> Here we tell the system that all frames from `begin-panic` to the crash location are not part of the application (including the panic frame itself). All frames above are, in all cases, irrelevant for grouping.

So basically, you want:

```
stack.function:_CxxThrowException       ^-app -app ^-group -group
stack.function:RaiseException           ^-app -app ^-group -group
```

In my project, I also had to add the following line (as first line) to make Sentry treat all other items as part of the app:

```
app:no +app
```

If all that doesn't work, perhaps there's another issue specific to your Sentry environment.